# Is is possible to initialize a new driver in already opened chrome browser page?

Tags: watir

Is is possible to initialize a new driver in already opened chrome browser page?
If it does, can anyone please mention how?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Watir starts a browser session by sending specific capabilities to the browser driver. While it is theoretically possible that there is a way to tell the driver to connect to an existing session, it is explicitly not supported by the specification, and its usage would be actively discouraged by the Selenium / WebDriver / Watir projects.

Comment: Thanks @titusfortner for advise.   So when you say theoretically possible and explicitly not. What does that mean? Does that mean watir and/or selenium might not allowed to do so? Please elaborate.

Comment: Like, I've seen articles purporting to do this, but not that I could replicate. Even if it could be done, the devs will all tell you that you shouldn't do it. :)

Comment: Great. Thank you

Comment: I believe there are also security concerns if code can just attach to open browser sessions that said code did not originate.  Browser security models should seek to prevent that kind of thing, which I suspect is another reason for the “actively discouraged” aspect of this.  That way lies spyware and privacy dragons